# Why does EntityCollection.Remove() cause SaveChanges() to raise InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

With the following DB schema:

```
CREATE TABLE master (
    id integer primary key autoincrement, 
    title text);
CREATE TABLE slave (
    id integer primary key autoincrement, 
    master_id integer not null, 
    title text, 
    foreign key (master_id) references master (id));
```

I created an sqlite database, which I then used to create an Entity Framework .edmx file.

Then I add a master and a slave record, which works fine, and then I try to remove the slave record, but that raises an exception and I don't know why.

```
var ctx = new blaEntities();
var newMaster = master.Createmaster(0);
ctx.masters.AddObject(newMaster);

var newSlave = slave.Createslave(0, 0);
newMaster.slaves.Add(newSlave);

ctx.SaveChanges(); // works fine, both id and master_id properties of newMaster 
                   // and newSlave are then set with generated values.

newMaster.slaves.Remove(newSlave);

ctx.SaveChanges(); // InvalidOperationException is raised
```

The message of the exception is:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**:

Here is the generated by EF `Createslave(...)` method:

```
public static slave Createslave(global::System.Int64 id, global::System.Int64 master_id)
{
    slave slave = new slave();
    slave.id = id;
    slave.master_id = master_id;
    return slave;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is still a slave object in your slave table that has no value set in the masterId column.

Try using `ctx.DeleteObject(newSlave)` to get rid of it.

Comment: When I add the slave, I don't have to invoke `AddObject`, but I need to invoke `DeleteObject` when I remove it?

Comment: @Ludo I think the `CreateSlave()` method already adds the object for you, or rather the addition to the master. Maybe they decided being explicit when deleting is better? You don't want to accidently delete something that you just wanted to assign to some other master.

Comment: I don't think it does. I updated my question with its definition.

Comment: @Ludo That's why i edited my comment, the addition to the master does that probably. Unfortunately, i can't remove the CreateSlave part anymore. Did DeleteObject work?

Comment: Yes it seems that you are right: no need for `AddObject` to insert, but `DeleteObject` needs to be invoked to delete. Even more so, it seems that only `DeleteObject` is necessary as it removes the object from the `EntityCOllection`.

Answer (score 1):

Your slave still exists and his FK column master_id needs a value. If you want to delete it completely, you need to tell EF to delete it, not to remove it from its parent. If you don't want to delete it, assign a new master_id or set this column as nullable.